# How to move CALayers along the z-Axis and apply perspective

Tags: ios, 3d, core-animation, transform

I've got a main CALayer which contains a few sublayers. I rotated the main layer by 89 degrees around the x-Axis, so I'm barely seeing it (it's close to being a slice in the middle of the screen now).

```
CATransform3D moveToOrigin = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, -self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f, 0.0);
CATransform3D rotateX = CATransform3DConcat(moveToOrigin, CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(89.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
CATransform3D finalTransform = CATransform3DConcat(rotateX, CATransform3DMakeTranslation(self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f, 0.0));

mainLayer.transform = finalTransform;
```

Now I want to move each sublayer along the z-Axis, so that it looks like a stack with spacing between the layers. Unfortunately, all I see is all sublayers flat on the main layer.

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.sublayers.count; i++) {
    CALayer *aLayer = _layers[i];
    transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, 100 * i);
}
```

The weird thing is that moving along the x or y Axis works like a charm.
Does it have something to do with that sublayer transform?

Is changing the zPosition property the same as moving the layer with  CATransform3D along the z-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When layers are rendered they are generally being flattened so even though they may contain sublayers with different Z values, the rendered layer is going to be flat. However, there is one layer class which doesn't have this behavior and it is called `CATransformLayer`. It doesn't do have any contents of its own but it also leaves the sublayers intact.